# I am not getting any CORS error on NodeJS (Works Fine with Node) but I am getting the error on React and Javascript while fetching API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors

NodeJs Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const port = 3000;

const router = express();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hi');
})


var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'URL',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'API_KEY'
  }
};

request(options, function (error, response) {
    
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(response.body);
});

router.listen(port, function(err) {

    if(err) return;

    console.log('Server Up');
})
```

JavaScript Code:

```
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'API_KEY'
        }
    };
    
    fetch('URL', options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Error:

> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
> pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your
> needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with
> CORS disabled.

Am I missing a Header in JS or is the syntax wrong?

Note: The API I call to  Get request is not my own.

Comment: Browsers enforce CORS rules, it's not a JavaScript thing. You don't have to worry about it from Node or other server-side code.

Comment: CORS is something that is enforced by Browsers. Not exposing your API Key to the internaet is also probably a good idea and not something that should be visible from the browser.

Comment: It's not clear whether you are having trouble making requests to your own API or another one.

Answer (score 0):

This **may** solve your problem:

Install `cors` and add the following line to the node server file:

`router.use(cors())`

If it doesn't work, remove any headers config and try again.